# Issues with creating HTML code generator - plain text and preview mode

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a form where the user (an employee in my company) can input a URL and the title of that URL to get the resulting HTML code. I know each user will be using Internet Explorer 8 so I do not need to worry about cross browser compatibility. **My problem is that I cannot seem to build a "preview" area for the code so the user can see what the end result is before they use the code.**

```
Enter URL:</td><td><input size="26" type='text' id='userInput' />
Title: <input size="31" type='text' id='urlname' />
```

When they click the submit button the GetURL() function is called. The input is stored in the following variable:

```
var userInputURL = '&lt;a href&#61;"'+document.getElementById('userInput').value+'"&gt;'+urlName+'&lt;&#47;a&gt;';
```

That variable is then placed in a textarea using innerHTML on the same page so the user can copy/paste the code to use wherever they need it. I also want it displayed in another area as real HTML. I want the page to turn the URL into a hyperlink so they can see what the end result looks like before they use it.

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = userInputURL;
document.getElementById('codepreview').innerHTML = userInputURL;
```

I had to use ASCII code to get around runtime errors in Internet Explorer 8 (the only browser the users will be using). I assume this is what's messing up my code preview section. If I do not use ASCII characters then nothing happens when the user hits the submit button except for a Javascript error.

**Could someone help me build a preview section?**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: previews built the way you're doing it will be subject to your whole document's CSS tree. If you're trying to to preview something that'll have a completely different set of CSS rules applied, you'll have to use an iframe so you can divorce the preview's css from your editor's css.

Comment: Are you saying the ACSII code I used to create my symbols (<>=) is not causing my problem? I don't mind if the preview section uses my CSS. Right now the preview section just shows the plain text version of the code. Not the end result.

Comment: If it looks like an html tag and you're putting it into an html context, browsers will treat it like an html tag. you'd have to encode html metachars to `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc... to prevent them from being rendered as tags.